# Does 'Grab some food' always mean to 'buy' food?

Tags: meaning

I was in a situation where all my classmates in college had a dinner together which our school prepared for us on our first day of school.  There were some cans of beverages on the other side and someone told us we can have them without charge. And some of us didn't hear that, so i said to them "You guys can grab some beverages over there."
Now i'm wondering grab as in 'grab food' can mean getting food free of charge as well  since I've always heard people say things like "Let's grab some coffee" meaning "buy" some coffee..
Does what i said to them sound natural? Or would there have been better ways to say that?

Answer (score 4):

From my understanding, "grab some food" is close to "get some food". So it basically means acquire food, regardless of the method used. So buying it or fetching it from the kitchen would both fall under "grabbing food".

Comment: Yes, "grab some food" is typical youth-speak for get (buy) some take-out food. So annoying, especially in light of most parents exhortations to children to not "grab food"...:)